# Should I send X-expressions over the wire, or should I compile down to XML

Tags: xml, lisp, racket

I'm writing a program that will send something similar-ish to HTML over the internet. The way my program represents the data is through X-expressions.

Should I send the raw X-expression over the wire, or should I convert it to XML and then send? Do I lose any fidelity from going from one structure to the other?

Comment: If you're only communicating with other Lisp applications, S-expressions are fine because you can use Lisp's built-in reader to process it. But if you want something more general, use XML or JSON.

Comment: Is there any benefit to keeping it in S-expression form if I'm only communicating with Lisps?

Comment: Yes, you can use the built-in `read` function to parse it.

Comment: There can be a great benefit, because S-expressions preserve type information. They distinguish lists from vectors, strings from characters from symbols, from numbers; floating point from integer.  Some Lisps have a circle notation so that graph structures can be serialized.  XML is just chopped up, nested text with no meaning. JSON has only strings, floating-point numbers, vectors, dictionaries ("objects")., and a few symbols like `true`, `false` and `none`.

Comment: Hey - can you make that an answer so I can accept it? That's really useful.

Comment: unrelated to your question but as soon as you are exchanging data over the wire you have to plan against which protocol versions both ends of the wire can understand, if you have an older client or an older server it might be a problem

Comment: Did you mean to type `X-expression` or `S-expression`?

Comment: @kjhughes A X-expression is one of several ways to represent parsed xml in Racket; see https://docs.racket-lang.org/sxml-intro/index.html and https://docs.racket-lang.org/xml/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the answers given as comments [by Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76327570/should-i-send-x-expressions-over-the-wire-or-should-i-compile-down-to-xml#comment134596688_76327570):

> you can use the built-in `read` function

and especially [by Kaz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76327570/should-i-send-x-expressions-over-the-wire-or-should-i-compile-down-to-xml#comment134596987_76327570):

> There can be a great benefit, because S-expressions preserve type information. They distinguish lists from vectors, strings from characters from symbols, from numbers; floating point from integer. Some Lisps have a circle notation so that graph structures can be serialized. XML is just chopped up, nested text with no meaning. JSON has only strings, floating-point numbers, vectors, dictionaries ("objects")., and a few symbols like `true`, `false` and `none`.

you also have the option to use the [`racket/fasl`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/fasl.html) binary format to transmit S-expressions. It offers faster loading and smaller size than `write` and `read`, at the cost of not being directly human-readable.